# NiFi: how to get maximum timestamp from first column?

Tags: apache-nifi

NiFi version 1.5

i have a csv file arrives first time like:

```
datetime,a.DLG,b.DLG,c.DLG
2019/02/04 00:00,86667,98.5,0
2019/02/04 01:00,86567,96.5,0
```

used listfile -> fetchfile to get the csv file.

next 10 minutes, i get appended csv file:

```
datetime,a.DLG,b.DLG,c.DLG
2019/02/04 00:00,86667,98.5,0
2019/02/04 01:00,86567,96.5,0
2019/02/04 02:00,86787,99.5,0
2019/02/04 03:00,86117,91.5,0
```

here, how do we need to get only new records alone (last two records). i do not want to process first two records that is already been processed.

my thought process is, we need to get maximum datetime to store in attribute and use QueryRecord. but i do not know how to get maximum datetime using which processor.

is there any better solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is currently an open issue ([NIFI-6047](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-6047)) but there has been a community contribution to address it, so you may see the DetectDuplicateRecord processor in an upcoming release of NiFi.

There may be a workaround to split up the CSV rows and create a compound key using ExtractText, then using DetectDuplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seems to be a work that is best solved on Nifi as you need to keep a state of what you have processed. An alternative would be for you to delete what you have already processed. Then you can assume what is in the file is always not processed.

Comment: how we can manage the state. do you mean UpdateAttribute state property. if so, can you please throw more clarity on that.

Comment: That is the problem, if you have to keep state Nifi is not the place where you want to store the state, it would be a hack to do so, Nifi should work without state, If you need to keep state you need to introduce a storage or a micro-service which will need a storage.  The least ugly work-around is what I mentioned whenever you read the file you clean it. so you won't need to keep a state.

Answer (score 0):

> here, how do we need to get only new records alone (last two records).
>   i do not want to process first two records that is already been
>   processed.

From my understanding, actual question is 'how to process/ingest csv rows as it is written to the file?'.

Description of 'TailFile' processor from [NiFi documentation](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-standard-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.processors.standard.TailFile/):

> "Tails" a file, or a list of files, ingesting data from the file as it
>   is written to the file. The file is expected to be textual. Data is
>   ingested only when a new line is encountered (carriage return or
>   new-line character or combination)

This solution is appropriate when you don't want to move/delete actual file.

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem as he need to know how many to parse, there are many ways to read CSV, split file, etc. The issue seems to be that he needs to keep track of a location and on file change continue from where he stopped.